# ACPI error while installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

My computer currently has Windows 7 installed and I would like to switch it to Ubuntu 20.04. During installation, I received this error messgage:

[image: ACPI Errors]

How can I resolve this to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS/UEFI to make sure the system is set to UEFI only? What brand/model of computer are you installing Ubuntu onto?

Comment: And before anything else, use that Windows one last time for updating BIOS or UEFI to the latest version published as it's usually easier to do it from Windows due to certain manufacturers insisting in providing Windows executable files only.